# Data extracted from memory using SharedPreferences not displaying

Tags: java, android

I have an Android game.Evertime the user matches the 'Power Rating' on the right block with the one on the left block,they get 10 points.The score is saved at every operation,meaning that at each +10 score,the score is saved with SharedPreferences on the memory.
Saving the data works just fine but when I close the app and reopen it,something is off:
the saved score does not display right away,instead it displays only when it increases by 10 (when the user gets 10 points,i.e. if I have 60 saved score and reopen the app,it displays 0 initially and if I get another 10 points,it shows 70,meaning that the 60 was loaded later and it is weird given that score is not initialised as 0).
Here is code:

```
//--------------------------------
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

score = settings.getInt("score",score);
/*---------------------------------
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
these lines are at the top where I declare the other variables for the game
*/

//----------------------
editor.putInt("score",score).apply();
editor.commit();
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//this code is in the submit event listener,where 'score' is also calculated
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you missunderstand the role of the second argument of

```
score = settings.getInt("score",score);
```

(see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences#getInt(java.lang.String,%20int))). You should use it like this

```
score = settings.getInt("score", -1);
if (score==-1) {
  //there is no "score" entry in the settings
} else {
  //continue with the loaded value for score
}
```

The line

```
editor.commit();
```

must be deleted. `.apply()` already does the same thing (apply does it asynchronously, commit synchronously).

EDIT: And did you write the line

```
score = settings.getInt("score", -1);
```

at the beginning of `onCreate` and **not** the Activity? It is not clear what you mean by "these lines are at the top".

Comment: thx for clarifying on that. 'these lines are at the top' means right below the onCreate